# Initialize variables on an Angular component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components, angular7

On an Angular 7 component I have the following:

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: PostModel[] = [];

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.posts = this.getPosts();

  }

  getPosts(): PostModel[] {

    let posts: PostModel[] = [];

    posts = postService.getTopPosts();

    return posts;

  }

}
```

Should I set this.posts inside getPosts() method?

Or should I return posts and set this.posts in ngOnInit as I am doing?

Is there a preferable way to initialise variables on an Angular component?

Comment: Personally I would return the post as this would keep your function pure. However its just personal preference. If the method was setting a value on the class I would use the setPosts naming convention rather than getPosts.

Comment: Miguel, ideally "the services return observables, the component subscribe to the observables". well, there're two ways to show a data from services. One is in a *ngFor show an array : < div *ngFor="let item of items>...< /div>, the ohter one is show an observable using pipe async < div *ngFor="let item of $items | async>..< /div>.

Comment: See that in the first case, "items" is an array ob object, in the second one $items is an Observable. In the first case, in ngOnInit you subscribe to the service and, in the service you equals the array items to the response, in the second one you equals the observable $items to the service. there're a lot of literature about it, you can see, e.g. https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794

Answer (score 3):

That's look better:

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: PostModel[] = [];

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = this.getPosts();
  }

  getPosts(): PostModel[] {
    return this.postService.getTopPosts();
  }

}
```

I personally do this logic aswell and, in a big project, it helps cleaning out what is going on when you have thousands of lines.